# Visual C++ Express 2010: "attempting to build a Win32 application from an x64-environment"

Tags: msbuild, visual-c++-2010-express

1) ran "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd /x64 /Debug" to set environment variables.

2) ran "vcexpress" from that command prompt. The reason for starting from the command prompt is so that the correct compiler and linker are detected. Otherwise they defaulted to x86_amd64  when vcexpress is run from the start menu.

3) attempted to build my project, a SuperBuild generated by CMake which calls msbuild to compile some static solution files. Received this error:

> You are attempting to build a Win32 application from an x64-environment.
>   If using the Windows 7.1 SDK build environment, type setenv / x86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to change the TARGET_CPU variable. When setenv /x64 /debug was run, it set:

> C:\Temp\cmakeex\build>echo %TARGET_CPU%
>   x64

I changed this to amd64, and the project now builds successfully:

> >set TARGET_CPU=amd64